# OpenCV cvtColor CV_BGR2HSV CV_32FC3 Saturation Range

Tags: opencv, hsv

I'm trying to build histograms for materials in OpenCV 3.2 but am confused by the HSV ranges--they don't seem to match the documentation, or I am approaching it wrong.

```
// cv::Mat bgrPhoto contains a test image

cv::Mat3f hsvPhoto;
bgrPhoto.convertTo(hsvPhoto, CV_32FC3);
cv::cvtColor(hsvPhoto, hsvPhoto, CV_BGR2HSV, CV_32FC3);
std::vector<cv::Mat1f> hsvChannels;
cv::split(hsvPhoto, hsvChannels);

// Documentation [0.0, 1.0]: measured here Hue to 360.0, Sat to 1.0, Val to 255.0
double minHue, maxHue, minSat, maxSat, minVal, maxVal;
cv::minMaxIdx(hsvChannels[0], &minHue, &maxHue, 0, 0);
cv::minMaxIdx(hsvChannels[1], &minSat, &maxSat, 0, 0);
cv::minMaxIdx(hsvChannels[2], &minVal, &maxVal, 0, 0);
```

Comment: OpenCV stores `H` channel values from [0 - 180], `S` and `V` values from [0 - 255]. For `float`, convert values accordingly.

Comment: H in [0,360], S,V in [0,1]. See [the doc](http://docs.opencv.org/master/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_hsv). Also you're trying to create an output image with 21 (CV_32FC3 evaluates to 21) destination channels. Use simply `cv::cvtColor(hsvPhoto, hsvPhoto, CV_BGR2HSV);`. Also `bgrPhoto.convertTo(hsvPhoto, CV_32F);` since just need to specify the type and not the depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you converted your image from 8-bit to 32-bit, you haven't scaled your values from [0, 255] to [0, 1]. `convertTo()` simply converts the types; it doesn't rescale the values by default. This is affecting your output since, from the [docs for color conversion from BGR to HSV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html), `V` simply gets set to `max(B, G, R)` (which will be a max of numbers going up to 255). You'll notice that in the docs for `cvtColor()` it says for 8-bit and 16-bit images, they are scaled to fit the [0, 1] range; but not for float images. However, the `H` channels and `S` channels still get scaled to the correct ranges because they use `V` to scale the image.

When you do `bgrPhoto.convertTo(hsvPhoto, CV_32FC3)` you need to divide by 255 to set the values into [0, 1]. If you check out the [docs for `convertTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) you'll notice a third positional argument can be set which is a scale factor. Simply using `bgrPhoto.convertTo(hsvPhoto, CV_32FC3, 1.0/255.0)` will, as the documentation states, scale every pixel value by that factor.

Also, Miki's point in the comment on the OP totally slipped by me but it was a great catch; check the [docs for `cvtColor()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab); the fourth argument is an argument for *number of destination channels*, not `dtype`, so `cv::cvtColor(hsvPhoto, hsvPhoto, CV_BGR2HSV)` is what you want.

Comment: It may be kind to mention that you can do this directly in the convertTo function: `bgrPhoto.convertTo(hsvPhoto, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0);`

Comment: Thanks @Miki, linking some more documentation now.

Comment: Thank you Alexander--outstanding answer!